# TFS Queries - How to determine who created a shared query and when

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are using TFS 2012 and have hundreds of Shared Queries that have been created over time due to poor oversight.  In order to clean these up and provide a common set of shared queries, we'd like to determine who created the queries and when, similar to work item type history.

Is there a way to find this information in the TFS UX, using an extension or querying the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the owner of a query in Team Web by looking at the security of a query, but it doesn't show the create date.

The data you need is stored in the `QueryItems`table of each collection db.

So, you should be able to get this information from a sql query like below, just change out the db names for your collection db.

```
SELECT t.Name as 'ProjectName'
      ,qi.[Name] as 'Query Name'
      ,[Text] 
      ,[CreateTime]
      ,[LastWriteTime]
      ,c.DisplayPart as 'Owner'
  FROM [TFS_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[QueryItems]qi 
  Left Join [TFS_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[Constants] c on c.TeamFoundationId=qi.OwnerIdentifier
  Left join [TFS_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[TreeNodes] t on t.ID=qi.ProjectId
  Where fPublic=1 and fFolder=0
```

Comment: Plus 1 for using Web Access to view the owner...very helpful.  I have not tried the SQL query yet, but I'm marking as answered.