# TFS2015 - List all user and shared queries with their owners

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to list all user owned and shared queries along with their owners from a TFS2015 database and I cannot find the owner of the user owned queries, it is always displayed as a null. I found a similar topic on SO that [returns shared queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193392/tfs-queries-how-to-determine-who-created-a-shared-query-and-when?answertab=active#tab-top), but when applying it to user owned queries, it does not return any owner.
I went through the records inside the QueryItems table and I cannot find any field that would point to the owner of a query.
Here's the SQL query I have been using so far:

```
   SELECT qi.Name as 'Query Name'
         ,c.DisplayPart as 'Query Owner',
          [fPublic],
          [fFolder],
          [fDeleted]
     FROM [Tfs_Development].[dbo].[QueryItems] qi
LEFT JOIN [Tfs_Development].[dbo].[Constants] c ON c.TeamFoundationId=qi.OwnerIdentifier
    WHERE fPublic=0 AND fFolder=1 And fDeleted=0
```

If there's a way to do this with REST API, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **Shared** Queries the key should be `WHERE fPublic=1 AND fFolder=0 And fDeleted=0`

So, just try below sql query (it works on my side):

```
SELECT   qi.Name as 'Query Name',
         c.DisplayPart as 'Query Owner',
          [fPublic],
          [fFolder],
          [fDeleted]
     FROM [TFS_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[QueryItems] qi
     LEFT JOIN [TFS_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[Constants] c ON c.TeamFoundationId=qi.OwnerIdentifier
     WHERE fPublic=1 AND fFolder=0 And fDeleted=0
```

Of course you can also use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/queries/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to retrieve the information:

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/queries/Shared Queries?api-version=1.0&$depth=2
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Explanation for the keys :

`fPublic=1` is for **shared** query, `fPublic=0` is for **private** query;

`fFolder=0` means the retrieved record is not a folder,  `fFolder=1` means the record is a folder (You can create folders to group the queries)

`fDeleted=0` means the query is normal used, `fDeleted=1` means the query is deleted.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer, but the private queries are not solved. I think I managed to do it myself with adding:
LEFT JOIN [Tfs_Development].[dbo].[Constants] cP ON cP.ConstID   = qi.ConstID
Now on a shared query I'm getting an owner via TeamFoundationId and the ConstID returns "Unknown Domain Acount" and on private queries TeamFoundationId returns a null, but ConstID returns a user, so each scenario seems to be covered one way or the other.
I hope I'm interpreting this right, because it's a little weird for me, that there's not one but two fields that identify the owner.

Comment: @W.Siegmund For the private queries the key should be `fPublic=0`, you need to know about the meaning of the keys first.

Comment: Yes, I checked it (in all cases assuming fDeleted=0):
fPublic=0 AND fFolder=0 -> private query
fPublic=0 AND fFolder=1 -> folder for private queries
fPublic=1 AND fFolder=0 -> shared query
fPublic=1 AND fFolder=1 -> folder for shared queries (just 1 instance on my server)
Please correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm right, I'll paste my solution and close this topic as solved.

Comment: @W.Siegmund Yes, that's correct, just see my updated answer for the explanation of the keys.

Comment: it seems better to join with Constants ON c.ConstId=qi.ConstId